# How to dynamically require files in Capfile?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, capistrano

I have a repo for multiple deployment with using capistrano-multiconfig [gem](https://github.com/railsware/capistrano-multiconfig). The problem is that for some applications I want to require sikideq tasks. Something like this:

```
if fetch(:sidekiq_enabled?)
  require 'capistrano/sidekiq'
  require 'capistrano/sidekiq/monit'
end
```

I guess that Capfile is loaded before the capistrano configs. How to deal with this?

Answer (score 2):

I was in the same situation, I wanted to require some gems per project and since my command line pattern is always the same to execute capistrano tasks, this is how I deal with it.

My pattern is like this:

`$ bundle exec cap project:stage namespace:task`

The solution was for me to get the first argument (here `project`) to know what kind of project it is and require the good recipe for the project.

So in `Capfile`, I write something like this

```
[...]

# Get project from the command line if any
current_project = ARGV[0].split(':')[0]
magento_projects = ["project_1"]
symfony_projects = ["project_2"]

# Include required tasks per project
if magento_projects.include?(current_project)
    require 'capistrano/magento'
end

if symfony_projects.include?(current_project)
    require 'capistrano/symfony'
end

[...]
```

Now when I type :

```
$ bundle exec cap project_1:staging deploy
```

Or :

```
$ bundle exec cap project_2:production deploy:check
```

It'll require different gems. Done :)